# Excel VBA Create AcroPDF Programmatically

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I have a form with a single button and the following code:

```
Dim ctrl As CommandButton

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set ctrl = Me.Controls.Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.commandbutton.1", Name:="CommandButton1", Visible:=True)

End Sub
```

instead of creating a command button, I want to create an AcroPDF control. AcroPDF can be found under the "Additional Control" option. I have found that each individual control has its own ProgID, but the list only shows common controls like command buttons and labels, etc. Not able to find AcroPDF ProgID Can anyone help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer on a random Korean website while searching on Google. Did not understand anything so I looked for key English words and the ProgID is "AcroPDF.PDF.1"

Comment: Nice work! You can mark your own answer as "Accepted", too :)

Comment: @DavidZemens hahaha yeah, most of the credit goes to you though through my other post. you helped me figure out the keyword I needed to type in google to search. Did not know what "ProgID" was or that was a thing. As my name suggests, I am a noob programmer :P